# Gremlin-Python: Switch traversal from edges to vertices

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I want to perform a [centrality calculation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#eigenvector-centrality):

```
g.V().repeat(groupCount('m').by('name').out()).times(5).cap('m')
```

using only a subset of edges:

```
g.E().has('some-property', 'some-value')
```

Unfortunately, the [`.subgraph()` step returns a dict](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#eigenvector-centrality) in gremlin-python, so I can't use it to perform further traversals.

Is there another way to combine an edge-oriented traversal with a vertex-oriented one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply some filter to your edges:

```
g.V().
  repeat(groupCount('m').
           by('name').
         outE().has(....).inV()).
    times(5).
  cap('m')
```

Comment: It seems like `.outE().has(...).inV()` will merely restrict the vertices, not alter which edges will be taken into account by `.groupCount()`.

Comment: i can't say i follow what you're suggesting. `groupCount()` is incrementing the vertex count each time the same vertex traverser passes through it. the `has()` is filtering edges and thus the adjacent vertices which will be considered on future rounds of `groupCount()`. so, the `has()` is limiting what is taken into account by `groupCount()`. if that doesn't explain the mechanics properly, then could you please add some more specifics to what you are aiming to achieve?